# React: Secondary element controlling active state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Below is my component. I'm trying to get links to close the slide out menu via changing the active state. The hamburger and so forth does this already but can't seem to figure out how to do it when someone clicks one of the menu items as well.

```
import React from 'react';

const HamburgerToggle = (props) => (
    <button className={"hamburger hamburger--squeeze" + (props.active ? " is-active" : "")} onClick={props.clickHandler} type="button">
        <span className="hamburger-box">
            <span className="hamburger-inner"></span>
        </span>
    </button>
);

const Logo = () => (
    <a className="logo-link" href="/">
        <img width="94" height="31" src="/img/logos/logo.png" srcSet="/img/logos/logo.png 1x, /img/logos/logo@2x.png 2x, /img/logos/logo@3x.png 3x" alt="Logo" className="logo" />
    </a>
);

const Navigation = (props) => (
    <nav className={"navigation" + (props.active ? " slide-in" : "")}>
        <ul className="nav">
            <li className="single-item">
                <a href="/">Home</a> //toggle active state ^^
            </li>
            <li className="single-item">
                <a href="#">intem 2</a> //toggle active state as well
            </li>
            <li className="single-item">
                <a href="#">item 3</a> //toggle active state as well
            </li>
            <li className="single-item">
                <a href="#">item 4</a> //toggle active state as well
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
);

export default class NavComponent extends React.Component {

    state = {active: false};

  handleClick(e){
      this.setState({active: !this.state.active});
      console.log(this.state.active);
  }

  render() {
      return (
            <div className="container">
                <HamburgerToggle active={this.state.active} clickHandler={this.handleClick.bind(this)} />
                <Logo />
                <Navigation active={this.state.active} clickHandler={this.handleClick.bind(this)} />
            </div>
        );
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems that you are passing in the `clickHandler` but never using it in your `Navigation`.   Add this `onClick={props.clickHandler}` to the nav items.

Comment: @RickTakes I've tried that. It doesn't toggle the Hamburger/Navigation state when I do that.

Comment: The state is not setup correctly in your `NavComponent`.  You'll need to add a constructor to your class or it will not fire the re-render correctly:
`constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  
    this.state = {};
  }`

Comment: Checkout the constructor section here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html

Comment: The result is the same. Just a different way of doing it. Did it this way because super is not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close to the solution, if you think about it, what happens when you click the `Hamburger` menu ? Where is this behavior specified ?

Now if you try to answer these questions for the `Navigation` items, you will find out where the issue is. You are passing down the props correctly, especially the `handleClick` which will toggle the state of the `NavComponent`.

If you go inside your `Navigation` component you can notice that you actually never call that method! There is no `onClick` in any of the elements that make up your component. So you are not specifying what happens when an item in the navigation is clicked.

I am avoiding posting the code solution because I know you can fix it yourself ;)

After the comments I thought it was worth it to provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zro2dLf6/2). You will notice that I changed how you update the state (although that was not the issue), it is a good practice to update the state with a function when the update depends on the previous state.

Comment: I'm trying. Working thru a few possible scenarios. I know that it's a bit more than onClick={props.clickHandler} though. I probably need to change the clickHandler too. Just hitting a wall here and it's probably something really small.

Comment: You are probably already doing it but add a `console.log` inside the method to make sure it's been called. Adding an `onClick={prop.clickHandler}` on each `li` element should be sufficient, but maybe we are missing something.

Comment: Yeah, definitely missing something. The method fires on the hamburger and the console.log shows it. Seems to do nothing on the list-item and anchors.

Comment: I can get the method to fire using: `(HamburgerToggle, props) => stateChange;` but doesn't set state. Argh

Comment: Now I just have to figure out a method around that because using a bunch of buttons in navigation is not going to fly...lol

Comment: You can use the Link component from the `react-router`, but you might already know this

Comment: I did not. Thank you for pointing that out...looking into now.

Comment: It's super simple something like `<Link to='/your_relative_path'>My Link text</Link`, but you need to import it first. And make sure that path exists in your routes.